# Moment problem on [-1,1]: necessary and sufficient conditions

Tags: reference-request, sequences-and-series, infinite-sequences, moments, hankel-matrices

Consider a sequence of real numbers $s=(s_0,s_1,\ldots)$. When is there a Borel measure $\mu$ supported on $[-1,1]$ so that
$$
s_k = \int_{[-1,1]} x^k\,\mathrm{d}\mu,\quad \forall k\in\mathbb N\;?
$$

The well known [Hausdorff moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem) asks the same question on the interval $[0,1]$. In that case, $s$ is a moment sequence of a measure supported on $[0,1]$ if and only if $s$ is completely monotone. It follows that, for our problem, the even terms of $s$ must be completely monotone. What is known about the odd terms?

> **Question:** Are the necessary and sufficient conditions for $s$ to be a moment sequence on $[-1,1]$ known? What are the simplest known necessary conditions?

The following question maybe easier to solve.

> Assume now that $s$ is a sequence of nonnegative reals. When is there measure supported on $[-1,1]$ with the moment sequence $s$?

There is a well known way of obtaining necessary conditions: Let $P(x) = \sum a_i x^i$ be a polynomial that is nonnegative on $[-1,1]$. Form the Hankel matrix $H_P$
$$
H_P(j,k):= \sum_i a_i s_{i+j+k},\quad j,k\in \mathbb N.
$$
Then we observe

**Claim:** Suppose $P(x)\ge 0$ on $[-1,1]$. Then $H_P$ is positive semi-definite.

**Pf.** Let $c_0,c_1,\ldots$ be a complex sequence with finitely many nonzero elements. We have
\begin{align*}
cH_Pc^* &= \sum_{j,k}c_j\bar{c_k}\int \sum_i a_i x^{i+j+k}\,\mathrm{d}\mu\\
&=\int_{[-1,1]} P(x)\left|\sum_j c_j x^j\right|^2\,\mathrm{d}\mu \ge 0.
\end{align*}

A result due to Riesz implies that if $H_P$ is PSD for all polynomials $P$ that are nonnegative on $[-1,1]$ then $s$ is a moment sequence. However if the interval is $[0,1]$ this PSD criterion is equivalent to a much much simpler condition: that the sequence is completely monotone. Is there a simpler characterization for $[-1,1]$?

Comment: I think it's easy to show that your condition for *all* $P$ with $P\ge 0$ on $[-1,1]$ implies existence of a measure as desired. You wouldn't expect a very easy characterization really since it's not straightforward to tell from the moments what the support of the measure is.

Comment: Another comment is that a (much simpler) positivity condition characterizes solvability of the moment problem, but with no restriction on the support. You're probably well aware of this.

Comment: I vaguely remember seeing that if $H_P$ is PSD for all $P\ge 0$ on $[-1,1]$ then $s$ is a moment sequence (Potentially named after Riesz). The reason I am hoping a smaller family may suffice is that for the interval $[0,1]$, considering polynomials $P(x) = x^p(1-x)^q$ for all $p,q \in \mathbb N$ is sufficient as per Hausdorff problem.

Comment: Sure. In this setup, we may say that the polynomial $P(x)=1$ is positive on $(-\infty, \infty)$ and $H_1(j,k) = x^{j+k}$ coincides with Hamburger's matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\mu$ is a measure supported on $[-1,1]$, the change of variables $y = (1+x)/2$ gives you a measure $\rho$ supported on $[0,1]$, and the corresponding moments are related by

$$\int_0^1 y^k\; d\rho(y) = \int_{-1}^1 ((1+x)/2)^k \; d\mu(x) 
= 2^{-k} \sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j} \int_{-1}^1 x^j \; d\mu(x)$$

Moreover, we can also go in the opposite direction to give $\int_{-1}^1 x^k\; d\mu(x)$ in terms of $\int_0^1 y^j\; d\rho(y)$ for $j = 0 \ldots k$.

So the necessary and sufficient condition is that 
$r_k = 2^{-k} \sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j} s_j$ are completely monotone.

Answer (score 3):

The following [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1988-104-04/S0002-9939-1988-0942632-2/S0002-9939-1988-0942632-2.pdf) answers a more general version of this question, namely the Hausdorff moment problem for compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This is a fairly broad topic, and you may enjoy learning more by looking at these [notes](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~monique/files/moment-ima-update-new.pdf) or [this really nice book](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/p665).

Comment: Of course, for answering the OP,  doing a change of variables to the 1D-case as noted by Robert Israel works!